# Eiffel: syntax error on multiple Generic constraint

Tags: eiffel

As per [this documentation](https://dev.eiffel.com/Multiple_constraints), I'm trying to constrain a Generic parameter to 2 classes and need a `default_create` creation procedure call in my implementation.

I'm getting a `Syntax error` from compiler on the `select` clause. Why is that so?

I thought first that calling `default_create` will call the `G` one which could be a merge/renaming/etc. but seems that on that level I have to call either one of both or both renamed which makes sense for me. But why does this syntax fail?

The context and my code is following:

```
deferred class
    IDENTIFIABLE_CASH[G -> {IDENTIFIABLE[ANY],
                            DB_ENTITY select default_create end} create default_create end]

inherit
    DB_SERVICE_CASH[G]


feature -- Access

    cash_from_identifier (an_identifier: like {IDENTIFIABLE_DB_ENTITY[ANY]}.identifier): G
            -- Returns firt entity found like given an_identifier (like operator is used)
        local
            l_qry: COMPOSED_SQL_QUERY
        do
            across
                cash is l_item
            loop
                if l_item.identifier.is_equal(an_identifier) then
                    Result := l_item
                end
            end
            if not attached Result then
                create l_qry.make (item_prototype)
                l_qry.add_constraint (create {FIELD_CONSTRAINT}.make (Void, identifier_db_column_name, {CONSTRAINT}.Like_operator, an_identifier))
                load_entities (l_qry)
                if items.count > 0 then
                    Result := items.first
                else
                    create Result
                    check
                        item_not_found: False
                    end
                end

                cash.extend (Result)
            end
        end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [page](https://dev.eiffel.com/Multiple_constraints#Introduce_a_select_clause_with_new_semantics) states that `select` clause is not part of the standard, and `rename` should be used instead. In other words, it's sufficient to rename `default_create` for at least one of two constraint classes, and use one version of the feature, e.g. `default_create`:

```
G -> {IDENTIFIABLE[ANY], DB_ENTITY rename default_create as d end}
     create default_create end
```

In the above case, `Result` can be created with `create Result` or `create Result.default_create`. The second version could be used as well:

```
G -> {IDENTIFIABLE[ANY], DB_ENTITY rename default_create as d end}
     create d end
```

Now `Result` can be created only with `create Result.d`. Finally, both creation procedures can be listed:

```
G -> {IDENTIFIABLE[ANY], DB_ENTITY rename default_create as d end}
     create default_create, d end
```

The last variant allow using either `create Result.default_create` or `create Result.d`.